# Web service within a Transaction Scope

Tags: vb.net, web-services, asmx

Please see the code below:

```
DeleteEvent = Deletion.ExecuteDelete(id)
If DeleteEvent Then       
    Using Scope As New TransactionScope
        'Database update 1
        'Datbase update 2
        'Database update 3
            etc
        Scope.Complete()
    End Using
End If
```

Deletion.ExecuteDelete is a call to an ASMX web service.  This web service was developed by a third party company and I do not have access to the code.  I only want the three database updates to occur if the web service
successfully deletes the record.  I only want the web service to delete the record if the three database updates occur.  How can I achieve this?

I am trying to say that the web service delete and the three database updates should be one atomic unit.

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: Among other things, ASMX has no ability to flow transactions.

Comment: OTOH, I found the following hack: [Using the Transaction(System.Transaction = MSDTC) between Web Services(ASMX)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowstransactionsprogramming/thread/09db9bf1-eda6-4525-8879-c2a40789b239/)